# Is there any way to load DataTables before showing original table?

Tags: javascript, datatables, styling

I am experiencing difficulties with DataTables. You see, I am loading JavaScript at the end of the `</body>` tag. So, when I load a page, it shows me original table without search and pagination for 1 second and then loads DataTables. So here is a question: is there anyway to load DataTables before page loads, so it will show DataTable immediately?

Comment: Before the page shows: no. But there are several options to prevent the FOUC.

Comment: And what are they?:)

Comment: One example: hide the table using css and show it after init. Other options: pass the data directly to datatables without having an intermediate HTML table.

Comment: Okey, thanks! Write it as answer. That solves my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43879304/5475228 this should be the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to prevent this FOUC, but you can not init the datatable before actually loading the page.

One option is to hide your table at the start using some CSS like `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` depending on your layout etc.

Another option would be to pass your data directly to datatables without an intermediate HTML table. You can find the respective [example in their documentation](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html).